# How to extract data from the Reality Composer recorded ARKit movie

Tags: arkit, reality-composer

I use Reality Composer to record an ARKit movie in the MOV format. Now I want to extract the RGB images, LiDAR data. How to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.